# OrientDB slow insert

Tags: java, performance, orientdb

I need to load around 5 billion vertex into OrientDB.

OrientDB documentation claims that each cluster can hold over 9 billion vertex and up to 10 billion documents could be inserted in a day. However I have been running for several days now and only a very small subset of my data has been created.

My model is very simple...

```
Person
-> Name   STRING
-> Score  DECIMAL
```

### 1.

I have left the OrientDB oetl tool running and it has inserted 500 million records in a week. Records are still (very slowly) being loaded at a rate of about 100 rows per second. It started at around 1500 nodes a second but has gradually slowed. Current estimation suggests a few months to load all the data(!)

### 2.

Meanwhile I have written a separate java app to test bulk insert

```
final OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:C:/orientdb/databases/test", "X", "X");
factory.declareIntent(new OIntentMassiveInsert());

OrientGraphNoTx graph = factory.getNoTx();

for (int i= 0; i < NUM_INSERTLOOPS; i++)
{                       
    OrientVertex v = graph.addVertex("person", "12");
    v.setProperty("Name", "test" + i);
    v.setProperty("Score", 100 * i);
}

graph.commit();
```

This too starts off very well, 100k nodes in about 8 seconds but after 10 million or so this suddenly seems to slow to over 5 minutes. I stopped it after 24 hours and 50 million nodes.

I am running a local database on a well-spec'ed Windows machine. CPU usage sits around 1% whilst running either process. The oetl is using about 15B of 20GB RAM, the java program far less.

Is this performance expected or have I misunderstood something. I am happy to wait several days to load my data but not several weeks (/months!!)

Comment: In `etl.json`, in the loader you have batchCommit set? Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/vitorenesduarte/ab72482b8dfc604ed736). Maybe it will help.

Comment: Actually I did *not* have batchCommit set, I set off a new etl import yesterday morning with this set to 1000. 

This seemed to start even faster, and has loaded 150 million nodes in 24hours - thank you for the tip. However again after 100 million or so nodes it suddenly slowed right down again, I am currently getting around 10 nodes per second...

Answer (score 0):

For java importer in NoTx to optimize you can use addVertex with inline properties like this.

```
OrientVertex v = graph.addVertex("class:person", "Name","test" + i,"Score", 100 * i);
```

this will will call only one time the save.

The next step to improve speed, is using multithread

Comment: Inline properties helped a lot, (predictably) cutting time by about a third on a subset of the data.

Actually I am already mutlithreading (via simple ExecutorService) but is there more to this in OrientDB - I notice there is an Orient DatabasePoolFactory...

Comment: If you want to try multithread you should set this property
graph.getRawGraph().set(ODatabase.ATTRIBUTES.MINIMUMCLUSTERS,n)
where  n is the number of your threads.

Comment: I have not managed to make much progress with this. At the current rate it looks like still several weeks to insert the 5 billion vertex I require.